# How do I check enable and disabled button using helium?

Tags: testing, automation, helium

[image]

The code of attached button is:

```
<div style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;">
<button class="prev btn btn-warning disabled" style="padding: 4px 8px;">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-left" style="margin: 0"/>
</button>
<button class="next btn btn-warning" style="padding: 4px 8px;">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" style="margin: 0"/>
</button>
</div>
```

How can I check that which one is enable using helium
I tried the following code

```
        click("Home");

        if(Button(">").isEnabled()){
        click($("html/body/div[6]/div/h3/div/button[2]"));
        }
        
        else{
        click($("html/body/div[6]/div/h3/div/button[1]"));
        }
```

But got the following error

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
> Cannot find element ButtonImpl(">").
> For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
> Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27
> 09:10:26'
> System info: host: 'Keya-PC', ip: '172.16.0.144', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
> '1.8.0_25'
> Driver info: driver.version: unknown
> at com.heliumhq.api_impl.GUIElementImpl.perform(GUIElementImpl.java:107)
> at com.heliumhq.api_impl.GUIElementImpl.bindToFirstOccurrence(GUIElementImpl.java:94)
> at com.heliumhq.api_impl.GUIElementImpl.getFirstOccurrence(GUIElementImpl.java:89)
> at com.heliumhq.api_impl.ButtonImpl.isEnabled(ButtonImpl.java:26)
> at com.heliumhq.API$Button.isEnabled(API.java:1276)
> at searchHomePage.search(searchHomePage.java:30)
> at mainClass.main(mainClass.java:19)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error: Cannot find element ButtonImpl(">")

We need to check the presence of the class (*prev btn btn-warning disabled* or *next btn btn-warning* ) in the code.

element ">" is not on the page is a picture.

**UPD:**

`if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("someXpath")).size == 0)`

or

`$(By.xpath("someXpath")).shouldNotBe(visible);`

Code in Java:

```
public static boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
```

`try {
   driver.findElement(by);
   return true;
 } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
   return false;
 }`

}

Comment: will you please elaborate